# Google apps script to merge multiple tabs on a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on merging multiple tabs on a google sheet and creating one master sheet.

```
function combinesheets()
{
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheets = doc.getSheets(); 
 var outSheet = doc.getSheetByName("combinesheets"); 
 for (i in sheets){ 
   if (sheets[i].getSheetName() == "sheet1") or (sheets[i].getSheetName() == "sheet2") 
   { 
     var data = getRowsData(sheets[i]); 
     insertData(outSheet, data); 
   }
 }
}
```

Using the above script I am getting ReferenceError: getRowsData is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

A line is in the wrong place there Cooper, it won't work.

Try this:

```
  function combinesheets()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var allsheets = ss.getSheets(); 
 var combineSht = ss.getSheetByName("combinesheets"); 
 for (var i=0; i<allsheets.length; i++) 
 {
var shtName = allsheets[i].getName();   
if (shtName != 'combinesheets')
   {     
     var sht = ss.getSheetByName(shtName);
     var shtrng = sht.getDataRange();
     var shtrngA = shtrng.getValues(); 
     for(var j=0;j<shtrngA.length;j++)
     {
       combineSht.appendRow(shtrngA[j]);
     }
   }
 }
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the function for you and it works on my spreadsheet.  It's a little slow but it gets the job done.

```
function combinesheets()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var allsheets = ss.getSheets(); 
 var combineSht = ss.getSheetByName("combinesheets"); 
 for (var i=0; i<allsheets.length; i++) 
 {
   if (shtName != 'combinesheets')
   {
     var shtName = allsheets[i].getName();
     var sht = ss.getSheetByName(shtName);
     var shtrng = sht.getDataRange();
     var shtrngA = shtrng.getValues(); 
     for(var j=0;j<shtrngA.length;j++)
     {
       combineSht.appendRow(shtrngA[j]);
     }
   }
 }
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```